# How do I close/hide this div with jQuery after it's opened?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following link will demonstrate what I mean. You click the first red box to show the blue one. Then, in theory, you should be able to click the little green button to close the blue box again.
It doesn't quite work the way I want it to.

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
 if($(".expand").is(":visible")){
 } else {
  $(this).children(".expand").show();
 }
});

$('.close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent(".expand").hide();
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: red;
  }
  
.expand {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  left: 256px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
  
.close {
  margin: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="close">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to event propagation your children div does trigger too the parent function.

You need to use stop the propagation with : `e.stopPropagation()`

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
    if(!$(".expand").is(":visible")){
 $(this).children(".expand").toggle();
    }
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).parents('.expand').toggle();
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: red;
  }
  
.expand {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  left: 256px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
  
.close {
  margin: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="close">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
    if(!$(".expand").is(":visible")){
 $(this).children(".expand").show();
    }
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent(".expand").hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: red;
  }
  
.expand {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  left: 256px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
  
.close {
  margin: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="close">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why minus to my answer?